# XSD Validation to throw exception with XPath to XML Node

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to implement XML validation against an XSD which should catch all the violations with the XPath to the Node of XML that is violating the XSD. My Code:

```java
package com.xsdvalidator.poc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class Xsd_Validator {

    static int errorCount = 0;
    static List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Validator validator = null;

    public static String Validate(String xmlString, String xsdPath, String delimeter) {
        try {
            if (validator == null) {
                loadSchema(xsdPath);
            }
            SAXSource source = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            validator.validate(source);
            if (errorCount > 0) {
                return "Error occurred (" + errorCount/2 + ") while validating XML. " + String.join(delimeter, errors);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error occurred while validating XML. " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            errorCount = 0;
            errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static void loadSchema(String name) throws SAXException {
        String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(name));
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new ExceptionCatcher());
    }

    static class ExceptionCatcher implements ErrorHandler {
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            errors.add(e.toString());
            errorCount++;
        }

        public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            errors.add(e.getMessage());
            errorCount++;
        }

        public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            errors.add(e.getMessage());
            errorCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

The XSD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xsd:element name="Employees">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="Employee" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Employee">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="Name" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="EmployeeID" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="EmailID" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="PhoneNumber" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="JoiningDate" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="Work" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Name">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="FirstNameType" name="First" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="MiddleNameType" name="Middle" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="LastNameType" name="Last" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="EmployeeID" type="EmployeeIDType" />
    <xsd:element name="EmailID" type="EmailType" />
    <xsd:element name="PhoneNumber" type="PhoneNumberType" />
    <xsd:element name="JoiningDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
    <xsd:element name="Work" type="WorkType" />
    <!-- Custom Data Types -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="FirstNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
            <xsd:minLength value="2" />
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z ]+" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="MiddleNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xsd:length value="1"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z ]+" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="LastNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="12" />
            <xsd:minLength value="2" />
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z ]+" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="EmployeeIDType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{1,12}" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="EmailType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+|" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="PhoneNumberType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{1,10}" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="WorkType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="PERMANENT"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="TEMPORARY"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CONTRACT"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Sample XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <First>Dev1</First>
            <Middle>K</Middle>
            <Last>Das</Last>
        </Name>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <EmailID>dev.d@email.com</EmailID>
        <PhoneNumber>8777000000</PhoneNumber>
        <JoiningDate>2019-10-31T10:00:00</JoiningDate>
        <Work>PERMANENT</Work>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <First>James</First>
            <Last>Bond2</Last>
        </Name>
        <EmployeeID>121212</EmployeeID>
        <EmailID>james.bond@email.com</EmailID>
        <PhoneNumber>8777111111</PhoneNumber>
        <JoiningDate>2019-10-31T10:00:00</JoiningDate>
        <Work>PERMANENT</Work>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

This is giving me an exception like:

```
Error occurred (2) while validating XML. cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Dev1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Za-z ]+' for type 'FirstNameType'.¡cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Dev1' of element 'First' is not valid.¡cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Bond2' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Za-z ]+' for type 'LastNameType'.¡cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Bond2' of element 'Last' is not valid.
```

The error is correct but I want the XPath of the element which is violating the rule. For example:

```
Error occurred (2) while validating XML. cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Dev1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Za-z ]+' for type 'FirstNameType'.¡cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Dev1' of element '/Employees[1]/Employee[1]/Name[1]/First[1]' is not valid.¡cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Bond2' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Za-z ]+' for type 'LastNameType'.¡cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Bond2' of element '/Employees[1]/Employee[2]/Name[1]/Last[1]' is not valid.
```

Is it possible? Any suggestion/code will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually said which schema validator you are using, and the JAXP specification doesn't define all the details of what might be available in the SAXParseException. If you're using Saxon's schema validator then the exception object potentially contains two paths (though the details aren't well documented): the path to the element that's not valid, and the path to the element that causes it to be invalid. For example if a FOO element contains a BAR element that isn't allowed by the content model of FOO, then you get a path to the invalid element (FOO) and a path to the location of the error (BAR).

Comment: Hey @Michael thank for quick reply! I'm not using Saxon. I can use any schema validator that can solve my purpose, changing code is fine for me, the only requirement is to use Java & something that wont cost me for enterprise usage.

Comment: I can't help with your financial problems, sorry!